# Object.defineproperty() set not working as expected , maximum call stack error thrown

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object like below , when a property `root` is defined on this object , i want the property to be modified, so i have the following code:

```
html = {};
```

and then i use `Object.defineproperty()` like so:

```
Object.defineProperty( html , 'root' , {
    set ( val ) {
      html.root = `${val} i got the power`
    }
});
```

Now when i try the following:

```
html.root = 'James !!';
```

I get an error saying :

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Why am i unable to add this property `root` with the modification.

Comment: you are calling itself....

Comment: What language are you coming from? because the other problem you'll have is a property that can be written but not read; you have no getter.

Comment: @Thomas, just realized what your saying , well iám i've used javascript quite a bit , just never used the browser method Object.defineproperty() before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create infinite loop with `set` method because inside you try to set property with same name so the same set method is called.

You can fix this by using `get` method and inside `set` method you use some other key name (for example original key + some prefix `_`).

```js
const html = {};

Object.defineProperty(html, 'root', {
  set(val) {
    html._root = `${val} i got the power`
  },
  get() {
    return html._root
  }
});

html.root = 'James !!';
console.log(html.root)
```

Answer (score 3):

`html.root =` will call the setter itself, wich will call the setter itself, which ...

You can't have a setter and its backing field under the same name, use a different field (e.g. `html._root`) to store the underlying value.